# yii2 redirect from custom module to base controller

Tags: redirect, controller, registration, yii2

I use dektrium user registration form.
registration link generates `domain.com/user/register` link
but it's not base user model, this module is located inside vendor/dektrium folder.
Now in base controllers folder I have UsersController with view action.
and after finishing registration I want to start view action of UsersController to view users page.

This is registration module code

```
public function actionRegister()
    {
        if (!$this->module->enableRegistration) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }

        $model = $this->module->manager->createRegistrationForm();

        if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->register()) {
            return $this->redirect(array('users/'.$model->username));
        }

        return $this->render('register', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

As you can see I've put there this code

```
return $this->redirect(array('users/'.$model->username));
```

Which is supposed to take user to it's own page at `domain.com/users/username`.
But unfortunatelly url is forming in the following way

```
domain.com/user/users/username
```

How can I fix this problem and direct user to `domain.com/users/username` page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra / in front of the users redirect. it should be

```
return $this->redirect(array('/users/'.$model->username));
```

Or you should actually create the url the proper way, that would be the best way to do this, but I do not know the way you have your rules set up so I cannot help you there. I am just guessing here but it should be:

```
return $this->redirect(array('users/view, 'username' => $model->username));
```

In this way you are using your url manager, not just hardcoding the url. In the future if you decide to change the link it will be much easier (replace just the url line in your config) and not go in files to change it.